# Estimate traffic when using cURL

Tags: php, curl, traffic-measurement

I have a page that loads another page in it via cURL. Similar to this:

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
echo get_data($_GET["url"]);
```

How can I estimate the amount of traffic of each request ? Say, user wants to display imdb.com at my page, I want to know how much of my server's bandwidth was used at this request (including images and all css/js files that were passed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kinda simple actually

```
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

`echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE);`